# ¿Como puedo realizar un analizador de sintaxis sql con determinadas reglas?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

Pretendo realizar un programa en C#, al cual por medio de un drag and drop pueda enviar un stored procedure. Lo que hará el programa será analizar la estructura del query (SP).

El SP, debe cumplir con ciertas reglas.

1. Después de una tabla física debe llevar with(nolock).
2. Una tabla temporal se debe destruir antes de su creación (esto colocando en el sp que se destruya en caso de que exista) y al final del sp (es decir debe haber dos destrucciones de la tabla).
3. Un update debe de llevar with(rowlock) sólo si es tabla física). 
   Entre otros.

Trate de hacerlo usando Regex, pero el problema lo tenía en consultas que tenían salto de línea.

Select *

From tabla with(nolock)

Por qué el regex sólo me leía por línea (select *) y me marcaba erróneo en el match.
Quiero empezar con algo "básico" ya que tendrá x número de reglas.

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al regex, el siguiente regex soluciona el inconveniente con los saltos de línea, lo puedes probar con [esta](https://regex101.com/) herramienta:

```regex
select \*(\n| )*from [a-zA-Z_]+ with\(nolock\)
```

Puedes usar la expresión `(\n| )*` para tener en cuenta los saltos de línea y los espacios dentro del regex. Ten cuidado con los espacios entre los saltos de linea y el `from`.

El tema de la tabla si es una tabla fisica es más complejo por que debes primero validar si el objeto que estás usando es una tabla fisica u otra cosa(como por ejemplo una vista). Ya habría que hacer validaciones adicionales para esos casos específicos.

Espero te sirva. Saludos!